# Why does Management Studio add the second alter table "CHECK CONSTRAINT" for a foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-key

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REMINDER_EMAIL]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
  [FK__REMINDER_EMAIL__FACILITY_ID] FOREIGN KEY ( [FACILITY_ID] )
  REFERENCES [dbo].[FACILITY] ( [FACILITY_ID] )

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REMINDER_EMAIL] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__REMINDER_EMAIL__FACILITY_ID]
```

Answer (score 5):

With foreign key and check constraints, specifying `CHECK` or `NOCHECK` enables or disables it.  *It's just explicit DDL* that is generated by the GUI that, in your case, enables the foreign key constraint:

> **{ CHECK | NOCHECK } CONSTRAINT**
>   Specifies that constraint_name is
>   enabled or disabled. This option can only be used with FOREIGN KEY and
>   CHECK constraints. When NOCHECK is specified, the constraint is
>   disabled and future inserts or updates to the column are not validated
>   against the constraint conditions. DEFAULT, PRIMARY KEY, and UNIQUE
>   constraints cannot be disabled.

Reference: [BOL ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

It is redundant and unnecessary, but I just take it as "verbose". If I was to defend it forcefully, I'd say it leaves the script reader without any question of functionality.

Comment: The syntax does seem redundant. I thought for sure it would have already been reported as a bug on http://connect.microsoft.com/sql/ but it's not there. Based on the priority they place on other "correct, but not 100% correct" scripting bugs, it's unlikely such a report would ever be fixed.